# Delegate with async callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

I found many questions here about delegate technique, and tried many variants, but still have BAD_ACCESS exception.

My app receives data from network asynchronously via NSUrlConnection. 
I'm using a special data exchange object with delegate to VC.

With NSZombies debug option I receive message: [MyViewController tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x79698490.

VC:

```
@property DataManager *man;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 ...
 man = [[DataManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
 ...
}

- (void) myDelegateSelector {
 // DataManager call this method when data is ready
... save data ...
 _tableView reloadSections ... // refresh content
}
```

DataManager:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <DataManagerDelegate> delegate;

- (id) initWithDelegate:(id <DataManagerDelegate>)delegate {
 ...
 _delegate = delegate; 
}

- (void) receiveSomeData {
 ...
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        ... receive data work in global queue
        if (_delegate)
            // going back to the main queue cause need to change on screen data
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myDelegateSelector:)])
                        [_delegate myDelegateSelector];
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: it means your MyViewController is being deallocated while you're trying to get it to do something. who creates/manages your MyViewController? Your code doesn't show what controller that is.

Comment: Yes, i know. VC created by parent controller. When the user taps "back" button quickly, data is still loaded and sometimes I get exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem succesfully solved.

Solution:

VC code:

```
- (void) dealloc 
{
  _tableview.datasource = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case, you should always remove a delegate in the dealloc method. For your view controller:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    man.delegate = nil;
}
```

You already make the check if (_delegate). Without setting it to nil when your VC gets closed quickly, _delegate is deallocated but not nil.

Comment: _delegate is a weak reference, why it is not nil when VC deallocated?

Comment: i'm not quite sure of the mechanics myself but it's kind of explained here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653841/why-do-we-set-delegate-to-nil-at-dealloc-if-the-object-is-going-to-be-destroyed And if you add breakpoints, you see that the delegate is deallocated but is not nil, and is some sort of memory pointer that is invalid but exists. if the delegate is non-nil, it will actually try to reference the delegate and make it perform the call, which will cause the crash.